# Calling Two controllers in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have began working on creating a website for displaying amplifiers with a comment section bellow.
I have thus managed to get my amplifiers details to diplay on it's own and similary with the comments/reviews.
The issue with my view however is that when I call both I get the error "Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: product (View: C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Term_One_Assignment_Benjamin_Robinson_U1655703\resources\views\product\product.blade.php) "

Now I know they work correctly seperately but never called anything like this before.

Web.php (route)

```
Route::get('products/','ProductsController@index');
Route::get('product/{product}/', 'ProductsController@show');
Route::get('product/{product}/', 'CommentController@comment');
```

Controller Amplifier

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
//use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function show (Product $product)
    {
        return view ('product.product') -> with (['product' => $product]);
    }

}
```

Comments Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

class CommentController extends Controller
{

    public function comment (){
        $comments = Comment::all ();
        return view ('product.product', compact ('comments'));
    }
```

Product View

```
@extends('setup')
@section('page_title')
    AmpCompare
@endsection
@section('page_heading')
    <h2>AmpCompare</h2>
@endsection
@section('content')
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Make: </h4></td>
            <td><p>{{ $product -> make }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Model: </h4></td>
            <td><p>{{ $product -> model }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Watt: </h4></td>
            <td><p>{{ $product -> watt }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Genre: </h4></td>
            <td><p>{{ $product -> genre }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Description: </h4></td>
            <td><p>{{ $product -> description }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Star Rating: </h4></td>
            <td><p>{{ $product -> star_rating }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Image: </h4></td>
            <td><p>{{ $product -> image }}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h6>Created at: </h6></td>
{{--            <td><h6>{{ $product -> created_at -> format ('l jS F') }}</h6></td>--}}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h6>Last updated at: </h6></td>
{{--            <td><h6>{{ $product -> updated_at -> format ('l jS F') }}</h6></td>--}}
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="back-button">
        <p><a class="button" href="/products">Back</a></p>
    </div>

    @if (count ($comments) > 0)
            @foreach ($comments as $c)
                <div>
                    <div><span><h5 class="user">{{ $c -> user }}</h5></span></div>
                    <div><span><p class="comments">{{ $c -> comments }}</p>
                    <p class="comment-created_at">{{ $c -> created_at -> format ('D jS F') }}</p>
                    <p class="likes">{{ $c -> likes }}</p>
                    <p class="dislikes">{{ $c -> dislikes }}</p></span></div>
                </div>

                <div class="icon heart">
                    <div><a class="button" href="/comment/{{ $c -> id }}/"><ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon></a>
                    <a class="button" href="/comment/{{ $c -> id }}/edit/"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></a>
                    <a class="button" href="/comment/{{ $c -> id }}/delete/"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></a>
                    <a class="button" href="/comment/{{ $c -> id }}/like/"><ion-icon name="md-heart"></ion-icon></a>
                    <a class="button" href="/comment/{{ $c -> id }}/dislike"><ion-icon name="md-heart-empty"></ion-icon></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        {{ $comments -> links () }}
    @else
        <div class="notification is-info">
            <span class="no-comments">
                <p>
{{--                    There are currently no reviews on the {{ $product -> make }} {{ $product -> model }} {{ $product -> watt }} amplifier.--}}
                </p>
            </span>
        </div>
    @endif

@endsection
```

I know this is probably pretty trivial but just wondered if anyone had any ideas as Laravel's fault finding is pretty awful.

Does anyone know why this isn't working and why it is throwing that error?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? but I can see that 2 routes are same. so it won't work with same route.

Comment: you can only do that if the other request is `get` and the other request is `post`, so for your case, just transfer your codes to only one controller and return all necessary variables on the blade file.

Comment: Hi I am trying to create a system like what is used by Amazon on their product pages. They display the product in this case from the Products table and then further down the page they display the Reviews in my case the Comments table. Ah I have used that before but only for updating my comments fields didn't realise the get function couldn't be called the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select one controller only then put all necessary codes on it, like so:

**Route:**

```
Route::get('product/{product}/', 'ProductsController@show');
```

**Controller:**

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function show (Product $product)
    {
        $product  = Product::find(1);
        $comments = Comment::all();

        return view ('product.product', compact ('product', 'comments'));
    }

}
```

Comment: just to add up, it looks like you do not know how to use `Route::resource`. Try to learn how to use it, it will make your route file cleaner. best of luck to your laravel journey!

Answer (score 0):

Very first you can not use the same route twice.

```
Route::get('product/{product}/', 'ProductsController@show');
Route::get('product/{product}/', 'CommentController@comment');
```

If you could do it something like this:

```
Route::get('product/{product}/', 'ProductsController@show');
Route::get('product/{product}/comments', 'CommentController@comment');
```

OR simply Keep a single route and access both (Product and Comments) with a single controller.

According to your shared view, It requires both Models data **Product** and **Comments** collection.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I have managed to get it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define same route in route.php. But first route will be ignored.

Please try to do following.

```
Route::get('product/{product}/show', 'ProductsController@show');
Route::get('product/{product}/comment', 'CommentController@comment');
```

Comment: Hi thanks that worked but unfortunetly I couldn't get them to display on one page alone.